# hyperlink to open different web page with specific element in focus AND active

Tags: html, focus

This problem refers to the main (header) nav menu on [THIS PAGE](http://lawyer.kirkfx.com).

When any of the items in the "Services" drop-down submenu is clicked, I want the "Services" page to open (in the existing browser window) AND for a specific anchor tag element on the "Services" page to be in focus. I've achieved this OK. BUT, when the targetted anchor tag is in focus, I want it to also behave just like a manual mouse hover had been performed on its parent div, ie there should be a slide-down of text corresponding to the focussed element.
For a manual demo, go [HERE](http://lawyer.kirkfx.com/services.html) and hover on one of the vertical list items - text will slide down to the right of the list.

HTML for the "Services" submenu link:

```
<li> <a href="services.html#collabSol" class="pagefade" onclick="var w=window.open(this.href, '_self'); w.focus();">collaborative law</a></li>
```

HTML for the targetted "a" tag and its parent div (ie "a" tag that should be in focus on "Services" page):

```
<div id="mylist1"><h3><a href="" id="myTag1" name="collabSol">Collaborative Solutions</a></h3></div>
```

Script to drive the hover behaviour of the focussed "a" tag and its parent div:

```
//fades in desired text after fading out whatever text is already displayed:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mylist1').mouseover(function() { //note first list item must be called mylist1 to avoid conflict with other code
  if ( !$('#text1').is(":visible") ) { //prevents re-display if desired text already displayed
$(".shownText").slideUp(100).removeClass('.shownText');
$('#text1').slideDown(300, 'linear'); 
  }
    });
//capture click events as well:
/* $('#mylist1').click(function() {  
  if ( !$('#text1').is(":visible") ) { //prevents re-display if desired text already displayed 
$(".shownText").slideUp(100).removeClass('.shownText');
$('#text1').slideDown(300, 'linear');
} 
   });*/
//capture focus events on <a> as well:
 $('#myTag1').focus(function() {  
  if ( !$('#text1').is(":visible") ) { //prevents re-display if desired text already displayed 
$(".shownText").slideUp(100).removeClass('.shownText');
$('#text1').slideDown(300, 'linear');
} 
});
});
```

Note the main nav menu has been created using jquery, via a Dreamweaver extension.

What I have so far:

When the "Services" page opens, the correct target is in focus (as shown by the browser address bar). However, this focus is not triggering the expected text slide-down event. When I hit tab, the next list div goes into focus (as expected) & the appropriate text slide down occurs.

Am I hoping for too much? Have I misunderstood the limitations of 'in focus'" Will Mt Hotham have a killer snow season this year ?
Your sage advice is greatly welcomed!
Kirk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure your use of "in focus" is quite what I expect... Having a fragment in the url doesn't necessarily give focus to that element, it just moves the display down to it. I assume the reason it works for tabbing is that tabbing does focus on elements and I assume it starts at the element that has been scrolled to.

What I'd suggest is breaking out your display script into a named function (so it can be used from elsewhere) and then on page load you can pull out the fragment from the url (eg #famLaw). Using that fragment you should be able to find the right element on the page and focus it.

It should be noted also that pulling the display text into a separate function has the advantage of consolidating your code - you are basically duplicating the code in the onfocus and onready events so breaking it out makes for easier maintenance and reuse. :)

P.S. I guess yes for Mt Hotham. I'd never heard of it before but I'm going to be optimistic.

Comment: thanks Christo - that should do it. One day I'll find time to teach myself about creating that sort of jscript function, and my web page will then be awesome (I'll call it chris.shtml).
As far as Mt Hotham goes, you aren't an Aussie skier I guess!! Turns out the season's going very well (best so far since 2000, andf this is just day #3). Yahooooo!